# Tips for speeding up ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, e-commerce

Hi im working on an ajax shopping cart using php and javascript with the jQuery library.  Does anyone have any tips in speeding up the ajax requests.

Also, are there any best practices with regards to locking the shopping basket or options to add more items with the request is taking place?

Comment: You're kind of asking two separate questions here.  You may get a mix of answers and it could be tough to select the correct answer.

Comment: Do the world a favor and don't support IE6! Not only will your app's javascript run faster, it will make the rest of us happy!  :)

Comment: It won't make anyone stuck on IE6 happy.

Comment: What's wrong with ajax requests speed **at this moment**? What are certain numbers? Got any profiling results?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer JSON over XML for data transfer just due to the reduced bloat XML gives you (closing tags).  XML definitely has its uses - just be judicious when you use one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing anyone can recommend is that you optimize your code, both front and back end. 
Make sure you don't have any unnecessary code etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to cache ajax content. It will speed up your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup in JQuery.ajax( settings ) client side caching. You can also do server side caching, but client side could be better solution in situations such as yours. If I remember correctly caching is on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you gzip what's being returned from the ajax requests, if you're not already.

Add this to your php files  `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`